# Ribbon Custom Action gone in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

As the title says, is the ribbon custom action template gone with VS 2017?

I have installed Office/Sharepoint development components and tried it with a farm solution as well with an add-in and couldnt find the ribbon custom action template when adding a new item to my project.

I have the professional edition installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vs 2013/2015/2017, There is no such template called a ribbon custom action, and to can create a ribbon custom action via VS 2017 you should add a **Module** or **Empty Element** as the following:

- Create a new SharePoint Solution.
- Then add New Item.
- Add `Module` or `Empty Element` as shown below.

[image]

To continue creating a custom action as Module check [Create a Custom Action for a specific list via Visual Studio in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/25/custom-action-specific-list-visual-studio-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: It is better to use "Empty Element", because you do not have to delete the .txt file and have also a cleaner xml file. But thanks for your answer as I understand that they removed it.

Comment: you are right for that reason :) meanwhile, the empty element template and module template has the same behavio

Comment: I do like the "Empty Element" approach much more than the "Module" one. I edit it and mark it as an answer.